# 401 response in IE browser NTLM authentication

Tags: internet-explorer

My application is based on `spring boot`, `Tomcat` with `NTLM` authentication. Somewhere from the authentication response in `IE` is giving `401` in IE. For chrome it is passed and showing response `200`.

Below is the response.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Fixed.

Solution is below:
You need to override the WebSecurity-Configure-Method in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and exclude some folder: as shown below:

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

  web.ignoring()
  .antMatchers("/static/**")
  .antMatchers("/images/**")
      .antMatchers("/js/**")
      .antMatchers("/json/**")
      .antMatchers("/inclu/**")
      .antMatchers("/lib/**");
```

}